# Jaeger: failed to init storage factory

Tags: kubernetes, istio, jaeger

I'm enabling tracing for istio using jaeger but the pod keep crashing "CrashLoopBackoff" and when checking the logs I get this error.
[image]
so it looks like a problem with storage (not sure tho) and I've tried to increase it but still not working!
[image]
as you can see in the second picture the capacity is now 15Gi and before it was 5Gi and the resize has been done successfully, I've deleted the old pod so it can be restarted using the new capacity but unfortunately I still get the same error and the pod keeps crashing!
any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: In the first image, I see health status as unavailable. Any idea why are you are getting that?

Comment: I think since the pod is unable to start due to the storage error then the pod will be unavailable

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Please edit your question and include errors as actual text.

Comment: I've recently seen a similar "Failed to init storage factory" error in the nodes that we look after.
It turned out that the actual problem was related to authentication failures (the expired certificate). Indeed it was misleading